# Get callback of onUpgrade() of Room Persistence Library Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

How to get callback when database is upgraded while using Room Persistence Library? I have provided Migration class to add/drop some columns in tables while upgrading Database.

Comment: What do you want to do, in a theoretical `onUpgrade()` call, that you cannot do in the `Migration`? When your `Migration` gets called, that *is* `onUpgrade()`, in effect, for whatever particular migration is called for.

Comment: you r ri8 @CommonsWare but If i want to take the callback of onUpgrde, I think it's not good idea to write code repeatably on each and every migration.There should way that simply give me onUpgrade callback.

Comment: @Moinkhan: "I think it's not good idea to write code repeatably on each and every migration" -- um, `Migration` is just a Java abstract class. There are plenty of code reuse patterns, if you have reusable bits of migration-related code. For example, you could create a `MoinkhanMigration` subclass of `Migration`, then have your `Migration` classes extend `MoinkhanMigration` and reuse code from it.

Comment: @CommonsWare There is one thing cannot be done in Migration. Migration is running in a transaction implicitly. If you want to perform DB vacuuming (especially after dropping the table) to reclaim disk space, you are not allowed to do it in Migration, because vacuuming cannot happen inside a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

```
// customize SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Factory 
public class DecoratedOpenHelperFactory implements SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Factory {
    @NonNull
    private final SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Factory delegate;
    @Nullable
    private final SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Callback customListener;

    public DecoratedOpenHelperFactory(@NonNull SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Factory factory, @Nullable SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Callback customListener) {
        this.delegate = factory;
        this.customListener = customListener;
    }

    @Override
    public SupportSQLiteOpenHelper create(@NonNull SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Configuration configuration) {
        final SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Configuration sqliteConfig = SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Configuration.builder(configuration.context)
                .name(configuration.name)
                .callback(new DecoratedCallback(configuration.callback, customListener))
                .build();
        return delegate.create(sqliteConfig);
    }
}

// customize SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Callback
public class DecoratedCallback extends SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Callback {
    @NonNull
    private final SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Callback delegate;
    @Nullable
    private final SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Callback customListener;

    public DecoratedCallback(@NonNull SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Callback supportSqLiteOpenHelperCallback, @Nullable SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Callback customListener) {
        super(supportSqLiteOpenHelperCallback.version);
        this.delegate = supportSqLiteOpenHelperCallback;
        this.customListener = customListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
        delegate.onCreate(db);
        Optional.ofNullable(customListener).ifPresent(customListener -> customListener.onCreate(db));
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SupportSQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        delegate.onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
        Optional.ofNullable(customListener).ifPresent(customListener -> customListener.onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion));
    }

    @Override
    public void onDowngrade(SupportSQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        delegate.onDowngrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
        Optional.ofNullable(customListener).ifPresent(customListener -> customListener.onDowngrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion));
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen(SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
        delegate.onOpen(db);
        Optional.ofNullable(customListener).ifPresent(customListener -> customListener.onOpen(db));
    }

    @Override
    public void onCorruption(SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
        Optional.ofNullable(customListener).ifPresent(customListener -> customListener.onCorruption(db));
    }
}
```

Finally, you can use Room like this：

```
Room.databaseBuilder(context, databaseName)
    .openHelperFactory(new DecoratedOpenHelperFactory(
        new FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelperFactory(), new SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onCreate(SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onUpgrade(SupportSQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

            }

            // etc
        }))
    .build();
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to provide Room Database callback as mentioned below.

```
return Room.databaseBuilder(application, WalletDatabase.class, "wallet.db")
            .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_3)
            .addMigrations(MIGRATION_2_3)
            .addCallback(callback)
            .build();
```

Declare callback as mentioned below.

```
public static RoomDatabase.Callback callback = new RoomDatabase.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onCreate(db);
        //DO AS NEEDED
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onOpen(db);
         //DO AS NEEDED
    }
};
```